# Most efficient way to see if number is contained within an unsorted two-number interval?

Tags: c++, performance

So I know this question may be very trivial and not worth asking since the difference is so small, but I'm wondering anyway.

Let's consider three float, 'a', 'b' and 'number'. We want to know if 'number' is contained within an interval of boundaries 'a' and 'b';

'a' and 'b' are the limits of the interval, but they are unsorted : 'a' may be smaller than 'b' and vice-versa.

Which function would give the fastest results ?

**1)**

```
bool isNumberInInterval(float a, float b, float number)
{
    if (a < b)
    {
        return ( (a <= number) && (number <= b) );
    }
    else
    {
        return ( (b <= number) && (number <= a) );
    }
}
```

**2)**

```
bool isNumberInInterval(float a, float b, float number)
{
    return ( ( (b <= number) && (number <= a) ) || ( (a <= number) && (number <= b) ) );
}
```

Comment: _Which function would give the fastest results ?_ Did you try profiling each case?

Comment: This code is full of branches so it will most likely suck unless your compiler is really good. If you want good performance, we need to know if all your numbers are random each time you call the function (making branches completely shitty since unreliable) or if they aren't, in this case we can try to optimize for the branch predictor. For example if `a` and `b` stay the same over several calls, the first method is likely better.

Comment: Smurf faster. The difference will be negligible, if any once the compiler's done optimizing, and the first is way easier to read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say which is faster. It depends on a lot of things (distribution of numbers, branch prediction, compiler). You should benchmark it. On my PC, with GCC 6.3, with uniform distributed [0;1] numbers, their speed is the same.

This variant should be faster on current PCs (it is 25% faster than your variants on my PC):

```
bool isNumberInInterval(float a, float b, float number)
{
    return (a-number)*(b-number)<=0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This likely depends a lot on the machine and compiler. But you can argue that the first is faster.

The first version will perform at most 3 comparisons and 1 logical operation. But it could perform as few as 2 comparisons and 0 logical operations, if you can short-circuit the `&&` when the first operand is `false`.

The second version's worst case is 4 comparisons and 3 logical operations. But it must perform at least 2 comparisons and 1 logical operation: you can't short-circuit both the `&&` and the `||`.